# Dynamic shipping charges in Shopify

Tags: node.js, shopify, koa, shopify-app, shopify-api

I was experimenting on `Shopify` since I started learning `Shopify` recently. I' a `MEAN stack` developer. One thinking came to my mind that how do we update the shipping charges dynamically?

Here is my plan,

There will be a `Google Maps` and the usine will pick the location. I've added few fields to the `cart.liquid` by reffering to [THIS](https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/cart-attribute) page.
I've created a small `Embedded App` to initiate the maps. The app uses `NodeJS`, `Koa`, `NextJS`, and `React` and I'm planning to create an  `Endpoint` with `Koa` where I can calculate the shipping charges based on the Geometric distance from User location to Store location.

The calculation will be something like below.

```
let latA = /* Store Lat */
let lngA = /* Store Lng */

let latB = /* User Lat */
let lngB = /* User Lng */

/* I'll caculate the distance using Google maps API. Lets say, distance is 10KM */

let shippingCharge = 10 * 50;
```

I can get this value and set it as `Cart Attribute`. But I want to collect the amount from the user, so, Is there any way to send this to checkout page as shipping charge?

I can't use `Shopify` shipping methods since my shipping charge will be created dynamically.

Comment: Is your store Plus? If you have a Plus store you can write custom Shopify Scripts via their app and modify the shipping price from there (this is available only for plus stores and you use Ruby to write them). If you are not a plus member then... you don't have a lot of options except using an external checkout process via an App or custom coding something.

Comment: I'm not a Plus user. Is there any reference to create custom checkout? I just want same checkout with this feature in it.

Comment: I haven't dip my toes there so I can't provide a lot of guidance on the matter. But if you need to create a custom checkout flow it may be a huge undertaking, since I don't think that you can rely on the checkout api for this (except the order creation) you may need to handle the payment processing yourself and the shipping, but once again I haven't had the pleasure of coding a custom checkout flow for shopify as of this moment so I'm not a valid source.

Answer (score 2):

Any store can add the Custom Carrier Services to it. You get an endpoint in your own custom App to return shipping costs to customers in checkout. The payload of data from Shopify to work with includes the **origin**, **destination** and some details on the **items** being shipped. It lacks real depth of course, but if you are clever, you can leverage product **properties** to customize a bit.

So you get to figure out how much to charge between A and B, for the items.

Comment: Can you please drop a code snippet or reference here? I'm new to Shopify, and trying to do it as experiment.

Comment: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/carrierservice